# Loading a Website inside a Website (possibly iframes)?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, window, embed

Let's say I have a webpage that's basically a sidebar full of links. I want a window to pop up with the contents of each link whenever they're clicked on. HOWEVER I do not want the contents of the links to load UNTIL I've clicked on them. Almost like a website inside a website. I've been terribly unsuccessful with my attempts thus far and I don't even know what to call it.

I know there's something called iframes, and I think it does something similar to what I want, but I can't figure out how to made the iframe load *only* once I've clicked the appropriate link. Not just hide.

NOTE: I am not linking to any websites other than my own!

Comment: A website inside a website? *"...We need to go deeper..."* :-P

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are looking for? Do you have an example somewhere you can show us, or even a sketch that will show us a visual of what you are trying to accomplish?

Your question is so vague that without more information it is very hard to answer you accurately, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

if you just want a link to load in a new window, you would use target="_blank" in the  tag. If you mean open in a new "modal window" or "dialog box" of some sort, inline with the rest of your content, then you would probably be using something like an  with AJAX to accomplish your goal.

Good luck.

Comment: Hmm. I'll be honest, the site loads fine for me. If you are are trying to load assets from another site, I would recommend you look into utilizing AJAX. This is a good primer on the topic: http://concentricsky.com/blog/2014/oct/ajax-faint-heart